# AfNetworking failure in AFHTTPRequestSerializer when I include spaces in the url

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking

I have a Get request with AFNetworking, the code is:

```
NSString *url = /*url*/;
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"text/html", nil];
[manager GET:urlMessage parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {...}
```

I have to include in the url some text with spaces. But if I do that, I have an error "Assertion failure in -[AFHTTPRequestSerializer requestWithMethod:URLString:parameters:error:]"
Obviously, without spaces, I don't have any error.
Do you know how can I include spaces in the url without errors?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you Encode the white space to any special character (say !@) and decode it in server side?

Comment: How to fix this - namely through properly encoding the URL components - really depends on the exact URL component which contains the spaces. If this is in the query component for example, then there are number of answers on SO how to accomplish this. So, please be more specific and update your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
ulrString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

It should solve the problem. 
Greets

Comment: This makes things worse, since percent encoding a whole and malformed URL (a URL string having partially improperly encoded URL components) will not magically make this malformed URL correct.

Comment: I resolved the problem in this way. Thank you! I don't understand what is the problem

Answer (score 2):

Try this

`[NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]`

You can also check these - `AFPercentEscapedQueryStringKeyFromStringWithEncoding` and `AFPercentEscapedQueryStringValueFromStringWithEncoding`.

```
- (NSString*) urlEnocodeString { 

    CFStringRef encodedCFString = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, 
                                                                        (__bridge CFStringRef) self, 
                                                                          CFSTR(" "),
                                                                       NULL,
                                                                        kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

    return [[NSString alloc] initWithString:(__bridge_transfer NSString*) encodedCFString];    ;
}
```

Comment: This makes things worse, since percent encoding a whole and malformed URL (a URL string having partially improperly encoded URL components) will not magically make this malformed URL correct.

Comment: Correct, Write your custom method to encode only Space.

Comment: Because your suggestion doesn't yield a correctly encoded URL. Even in the simplest case, where a _value_ of the query component would contain a space, `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` will not yield a correctly encoded URL. Example: given an invalid URL: `@"http://example.com?name=ab cd"` after percent encoding we get: `http://example.com?name=ab%20cd`, but it shall be: `http://example.com?name=ab+cd`

Answer (score 0):

It's not reccomended using spaces in URL.
Anyway you have to URL encode your URL to replace spaces

Comment: Why is it not recommended?

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 9 this will work :

Objective-C:

```
[query stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:
        [NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
```